# Is this sentence grammatically and structurally correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> The premise of reducing crime rates in urban environments is hardly conceivable, understanding not these situations and conditions.

Does it simply mean:

> without comprehending some situations and conditions, we can't reduce crime rates.

?

Comment: Where did you get the statement from?  Is there more information before or after the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your second quote seems to be an accurate interpretation.

It is possible that the first sentence is grammatically correct, but it sounds pretty horrid and would never be used in spoken English (its similar to Yoda-speak).

Changing

> understanding not

to

> without understanding

and removing the comma would convert it into everyday English.